# Подключение к устройству по BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth

Есть такая проблема - на Android 4.3 при каждом подключении к устройству по BLE тратится время для поиска сервисов и характеристик устройства. Это занимает 1-4 секунды.
Возможно ли отменить поиск сервисов для экономии времени, если все необходимые UUID сервисов уже известны? Спасибо!

PS: на старших API, вроде как, более глубокая поддержка BLE, и там, возможно, такой проблемы нет, но хотелось бы решить проблему именно на этом API.

Comment: **startLeScan(UUID[], BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)** https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback) пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал, в этом случае не находится ни одного устройтсва(

Answer (score 1):

Нужен `Gatt` обьект, в котором должны быть все сервисы, характеристики и дескрипторы... Так как именно такой обьект возвращаеться методом `onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)`, то я думаю, что это делать необходимо. Разве что попробовать сохранять состояние `Gatt` обьекта с сервисами и тд. и обходиться только соеденением.